# JavaScript - Passed string argument become undefined in recursive call

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

// In this code I am trying to print all paths in a 2D matrix. Where in each step I can move only right or down direction

```
var n = 3;
var m = 3;
var total = 0;


function mazePath(start,end,n,m,count,output){
        if(start==(n-1) && end==(m-1)){
            console.log(output); // It print undefined
            total = total+1;
            return;
        }
        if(start>=n || end>=m){
            return; 
        }
        mazePath(start+1,end,n,m,count,output+"D"); // call for down direction
        mazePath(start,end+1,n,m,output+"R"); // call for right direction


}
```

// Here initialising the string variable

```
var str = '';
```

// calling the function
mazePath(0,0,n,m,0,str);

```
console.log(" Total path is "+total);


When I try to run this code it gives following result - 

(base) satyendras-MacBook-Air:cooding satyendra$ node path.js 
undefined
undefined
undefinedD
undefined
undefinedD
undefinedDD
 Total path is 6

Please help me what is wrong with this code.
```

Comment: `mazePath(start,end+1,n,m,output+"R")` only passes five arguments. When using recursion, the result is usually returned; keep that in mind.

Comment: @Sebastian - Thanks . Now my code is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing one parameter in the second function call:

```
 mazePath(start,end+1,n,m,output+"R"); // call for right direction
```

You are only calling 5 parameters and missing the "count" one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . It was a silly mistake.